# Fibonacci $\equiv -1 \mod p^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, fibonacci-numbers

Is there a prime $p > 3$ such that the Fibonacci number $F_{np} \equiv -1 \mod p^2$ for some natural number $n$?  I know none of the first $1000$ primes $> 3$ qualify.

EDIT: In response to Calvin Lin's comment: 
Suppose $n$ is the period mod $p$. Of course the period mod $p^2$ is a multiple of $n$. If $M = \pmatrix{1 & 1\cr 1 & 0\cr}$, so that $M^k = \pmatrix{F_{k+1} & F_k\cr F_k & F_{k-1}\cr}$, that says 
$M^n \equiv I \mod p$, so $M^n \equiv I + p A \mod p^2$ for some matrix $A$
with entries in $\mathbb Z_p$.  Then $M^{kn} \equiv I + k p A \mod p^2$.  If $A = 0$, the period mod $p^2$ is $n$, otherwise it is $pn$.

Note that $n$ divides $p-1$ (if $p \equiv \pm 4 \mod 5$) or $2p+2$ (if $p \equiv \pm 3 \mod 5$), and in either case is coprime to $p$.  Thus if the period mod $p^2$ is not $pn$, $p$ must be
a Fibonacci-Wieferich prime (see Noam Elkies' answer).

Comment: How are you indexing your Fibonacci numbers? $F_0 = 0, F_1 = 1$?

Comment: Yes, that's how.

Comment: So $F_6 = 8 \equiv -1 \pmod 9?$

Comment: @WillJagy Other than p > 3, it satisfies the conditions

Comment: @CalvinLin, I'm just confirming the numbering, the reason for requiring $p>3$ and so on. Sometimes I do monster computer runs on these problems, I like to be sure what I am looking at.

Comment: @WillJagy Yes, that's why I asked for $p > 3$.

Comment: Robert, thanks.

Comment: How you prove for a prime $3<p<1000$ that *there is no such $n$*?

Comment: @Berci, these things are periodic $\pmod p$ as well as $\pmod {p^2}.$ There are only $p^2 - 1$ ordered pairs $\mod p.$ I'm still fiddling with it, but for some primes, whenever the count is divisible by $p,$ we cannot even get $-1 \pmod p.$ My next step is a list of small primes for which the thing can be solved for $\pmod p.$

Comment: @Berci: find period of Fibonacci sequence mod $p^2$ and check each candidate...

Comment: Here's an interesting conjecture: If the period mod $p$ is $n$, then the period mod $p^2$ is $np$. Having the period mod $p^2$ be a multiple of $p$ is a necessary, but not sufficient, condition for there to be no such primes.

Comment: Now confirmed for primes $3 < p < 65536$.

Comment: It will probably will become famous Israel's conjecture in the future!

Comment: @RobertIsrael Confirmed for primes $3\lt p \lt 100000$

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The set of such primes $p$ is probably infinite but very sparse,
and there are no such $p < 2 \cdot 10^{14}$.

We show that $p$ must be a "Fibonacci-Wieferich prime", i.e. a prime for which
$F_k \equiv 0 \bmod p^2$ for some $k \not\equiv 0 \bmod p$;
as with ordinary Wieferich primes (primes such as $1093$ and $3511$ for which
$2^p \equiv 2 \bmod p^2$), the number of such $p \leq x$ is expected
to grow as $\log \log x$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$.
Conversely, any Fibonacci-Wieferich prime $p$ will admit a congruence
$F_{np} \equiv -1 \bmod p^2$.

Suppose $p>5$.
Recall that $F_m = (\varphi^m - \overline\varphi^m) / \sqrt{5}$,
where $\varphi, \overline\varphi = (1 \pm \sqrt5) / 2$
with $\varphi \overline\varphi = -1$.
Hence if $F_m \equiv -1 \bmod p^2$ then $\varphi^m \bmod p^2$
is a root of $X^2 + \sqrt5 \, X - (-1)^m = 0$.
Thus if $m$ is odd then
$$
\varphi^m = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}
= -\varphi \ \ \text{or} \ \ \varphi^{-1},
$$
while if $m$ is even then
$$
\varphi^m = \frac{-3 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}
= -\varphi^2 \ \ \text{or} \ \ -\!\varphi^{-2}.
$$
[This even case is where we must assume $p \neq 3$, because
the discriminant of $X^2 + \sqrt5 \, X - 1$ is $9 \equiv 0 \bmod 3$,
so $\phi^m$ can be congruent to one of its roots only modulo 3
but still satisfy the quadratic equation modulo 9.]
Thus if $m$ is odd then $\varphi^{m+1}$ or $-\varphi^{m-1}$ is $1 \bmod p^2$,
while if $m$ is even then $-\varphi^{m+2}$ or $-\varphi^{m-2}$ is $1 \bmod p^2$.
In each of these four cases, then,
if $m=np$ then $\varphi^k \equiv 1 \bmod p^2$ for some
$k$ that is not a multiple of $p$ (namely $k = m+1$, $2m-2$, or $2m\pm 4$).
This makes $p$ a Fibonacci-Wieferich prime.  The paper

> Richard J. McIntosh and Eric L Roettger:
>   [A search for
>     Fibonacci-Wieferich and Wolstenholme primes](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2007-76-260/S0025-5718-07-01955-2/S0025-5718-07-01955-2.pdf),
>   *Math. of Computation* **76** #260 (2007), 2087-2094.

explains why we expect the $\log \log x$ behavior, and reports on an
exhaustive search over $p < 2 \cdot 10^{14}$ that came up empty.

solutions $m$ of $F_m \equiv -1 \bmod p^2$ should include multiples of $p$.

Conversely, if $p$ is a Fibonacci-Wieferich prime then there exists some
*even* $k \not\equiv 0 \bmod p$ such that $\varphi^k \equiv 1 \bmod p^2$.
(If the smallest $k$ was odd then double it.)  By "Chinese Remainder"
$k$ has a multiple $k' \equiv 1 \bmod p$, and this $k'$ is again even with
$\varphi^{k'} \equiv 1 \bmod p^2$.  Therefore $F_{np} \equiv -1 \bmod p^2$
with $np = k'-1$ odd, QED.

Comment: I don't get how you deduce that $\varphi^m$ has to be a root of $X^2 + \sqrt 5 X + (-1)^m$

Comment: Sorry, I switched even and odd $m$; I'll fix it next.  The argument is:
$\varphi^m - \varphi^{-m} = -\sqrt 5$, and
$\varphi^m \cdot \varphi^{-m} = (-1)^m$, so
$X = \varphi^m$ satisfies $X - (-1)^m/X = -\sqrt 5$,
whence $X^2 +\sqrt 5 - (-1)^m = 0$.

Comment: Happily the corrected version also makes the Fibonacci-Wieferich condition
sufficient as well as necessary.

Comment: [typo in my first comment: the final equation is
$X^2 +\sqrt 5 \, X - (-1)^m = 0$ as earlier, not
$X^2 +\sqrt 5 - (-1)^m = 0$.]

Comment: alright, also it's just $(X-\phi^m)(X+\overline{\phi}^m)$ and that threw me off. Also, I think you have a few wrong signs in the following two lines, at least the $\pm$ should be in fron of $1$ and $3$ and not $\sqrt 5$, but it shouldn't break everything.

Comment: I think that's right, but won't be able to check and (presumably) re-edit
until later today.  As long as $\varphi^m = X = \varphi^{-1}$ remains 
a solution with $m$ odd, the converse implication (FibWief is also sufficient)
will still hold.  Thanks for your careful reading.